# Solution verification of expressing one variable in terms of other, used in Schweinler-Wigner orthogonalization procedures.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, orthogonality

I don't understand how $$\mathbf{w}_{\kappa}=\sum_{k} p_{\kappa}^{-\frac{1}{2}} u_{k \kappa} \mathbf{v}_{k}\implies\mathbf{v}_{k}=\sum_{\kappa} u_{k \kappa}^{*} p_{\kappa}^{\frac{1}{2}} \mathbf{w}_{k}$$ given $\sum_{\kappa=1}^{n} u_{k \kappa}^{*} u_{\ell \kappa}=\delta_{k l}$.

---

When I tried to solve it, I got an extra summation:

We have $\omega_{\kappa}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_{\kappa}^{-1 / 2} u_{k \kappa} v_{k}$ so $$u_{k \kappa}^{*} p_{\kappa}^{1 / 2} \omega_{\kappa}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} u_{k \kappa}^{*} p_{\kappa}^{1 / 2} p_{\kappa}^{-1 / 2} u_{k \kappa} v_{k}\implies\sum_{\kappa=1}^{n} u_{k \kappa}^{*} p_{\kappa}^{1 / 2} \omega_{\kappa}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{\kappa=1}^{n} u_{k \kappa}^{*} u_{k \kappa}\right) v_{k}.$$ Since $\sum_{\kappa=1}^{n} u_{k \kappa}^{*} u_{\ell \kappa}=\delta_{k l}$, it follows that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} u_{k \kappa}^{*} p^{1/2} \omega_{\kappa}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\delta_{k k}\right) v_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} v_{k}.$$

For more details on this problem see equations $(3')$, $(6)$ and $(6')$ of [Schweinler (1970)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5ZpF.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that because $u_{k\kappa}^*$ is dependent on $k$ we cannot place it inside the summation. So \begin{align}\mathbf{w}_{\kappa}=\sum_{k} p_{\kappa}^{-1/2} u_{k \kappa} \mathbf{v}_{k}&\implies u_{k \kappa}^{*} p_{\kappa}^{1/2} \mathbf{w}_{\kappa}=u_{k \kappa}^{*}\sum_kp_{\kappa}^{1 / 2} p_{\kappa}^{-1 / 2}u_{k \kappa}\mathbf{v}_{k}=u_{k \kappa}^{*}\sum_ku_{k \kappa}\mathbf{v}_{k}\\&\implies\sum_\kappa u_{k \kappa}^{*} p_{\kappa}^{1/2} \mathbf{w}_{\kappa}=\sum_\kappa u_{k \kappa}^{*}\sum_ku_{k \kappa}\mathbf{v}_{k}\end{align} By grouping in terms of ${\mathbf v}_k$, this can be rewritten as \begin{align}\sum_\kappa u_{k \kappa}^{*}\sum_ku_{k \kappa}\mathbf{v}_{k}&=\sum_\ell\left(\sum_\kappa u_{k\kappa}^*u_{\ell\kappa}\right){\mathbf{v}}_\ell=\sum_\ell\delta_{k\ell}{\mathbf{v}}_\ell\end{align} by the normalisation identity. The sum is zero except when $\ell=k$, so ${\mathbf v}_k=\sum_\kappa u_{k \kappa}^{*} p_{\kappa}^{1/2} \mathbf{w}_{\kappa}$.